# The derivative of the trigonometric polynomial

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, trigonometric-series

For $n\in\mathbb{N}$, let $\varphi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a $4n-$ periodic function s.t.
$$\varphi(t)=n-|n-t|,\quad  -n\leq t\leq 3n$$
For each $j\in\mathbb{Z}$ define
$$c_j=\int_0^1\varphi(4n t)e^{-2\pi ij t}dt$$

(i) Show that
$$\sum_{j\in\mathbb{Z}}|c_j|=n.$$

(ii) Let $Q_n(x)=\sum_{k=-n}^na_ke^{2\pi ik x}$ be a trigonometric polynomial of degree $n$, show that
$$Q_n'(x)=2\pi i\sum_{j\in\mathbb{Z}}c_jQ_n\left(x+\frac{j}{4n}\right)$$

For (i), I got
$$c_j=\begin{cases}\frac{4ni}{\pi^2j^2}\sin\left(\frac{\pi j}{2}\right), &j\text{ odd}\\
0, &j\text{ even}\end{cases}$$
thus (i) is quite straight forward.

I've been really struggling on (ii) for a while. I wrote
$$\begin{aligned}
c_jQ_n\left(x+\frac{j}{4n}\right)&=c_j\sum_{k=-n}^{n}a_ke^{2\pi ikx}e^{\frac{\pi ikj}{2n}}\\
&=\frac{2n}{\pi^2 j^2}(e^{\frac{\pi ij}{2}}-e^{-\frac{\pi ij}{2}})\sum_{k=-n}^{n}a_ke^{2\pi ikx}e^{\frac{\pi ikj}{2n}}\\
&=\frac{2n}{\pi^2 j^2}\sum_{k=-n}^{n}a_ke^{2\pi ikx}(e^{\frac{\pi i(k+n)j}{2n}}-e^{\frac{\pi i(k-n)j}{2n}})
\end{aligned}$$
for all odd $j$, so
$$\sum_{j\in\mathbb{Z}}c_jQ_n\left(x+\frac{j}{4n}\right)=\sum_{k=-n}^{n}a_ke^{2\pi ikx}\sum_{j\in\mathbb{Z}, j\text{odd}}\frac{2n}{\pi^2 j^2}(e^{\frac{\pi i(k+n)j}{2n}}-e^{\frac{\pi i(k-n)j}{2n}})$$
At this point I am stuck. Is there any trick to prove the result? Thanks in advance.